# Why does this Groovy date assertion fail?

Tags: groovy, assertions

I have this very simple script for using date ranges in Groovy. It is as follows:

```
def today = new Date()
def yesterday = today - 1
def tomorrow = today + 1
assert [yesterday..tomorrow].contains(today)
assert [yesterday..tomorrow].size() == 3
```

The assertion fails and I get the error:

```
Assertion failed: 

assert [yesterday..tomorrow].contains(today)
        |          |         |        |
        |          |         false    Sun Aug 17 00:24:17 IST 2014
        |          Mon Aug 18 00:24:17 IST 2014
        Sat Aug 16 00:24:17 IST 2014
```

Which is strange because Saturday to Monday does contain Sunday.

The only reason I can think for the assertion to fail is if the week starts on Sunday then Sunday does not fall between Saturday and Monday.

But the way I have my script, shouldn't the assertion pass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it shouldn't.

You've put the range inside a collection, i.e., a list with the range as its single element.

Instead, do this:

```
today     = new Date()
yesterday = today - 1
tomorrow  = today + 1

assert (yesterday..tomorrow).contains(today)
assert (yesterday..tomorrow).size() == 3
```

Always check your assumptions, e.g., check the type and length of what you're calling methods on:

```
[yesterday..tomorrow].size      => 1
[yesterday..tomorrow].class     => class java.util.ArrayList
[yesterday..tomorrow][0].class  => class groovy.lang.ObjectRange
```